# Work with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing some game at c++. The problem is with arrays. It always shows the 'desk' with points (empty parts). Need comments are in the code:

```
void showDesk(int someArray[][3])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3 ;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(someArray [i][j] == 0)      cout << ".";
            else if (someArray[i][j] == 1) cout << "x";
            else if (someArray[i][j] == 2) cout << "o";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}

void newDesk (int someArray[][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            someArray [i][j] = 0;
}

bool empty(int someArray[][3], int x, int y)
{
    if (someArray[x][y] == 0)
        return true;       // It returns true
    else
        return false;
}

void setMark(int someArray[][3],int x,int y,int mark)
{
    if (empty(someArray,x,y))
        someArray [x][y] == mark; // But this never calls!
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   int x,y;
   int mark;

   int someArray [3][3];

   newDesk(someArray);
   showDesk(someArray);
   cout << "------------------\n";

   while (true)
   {
       cout<< "put x,y\n";
       cin >> x>>y;

       cout << "put mark\n";
       cin >> mark;

       setMark(someArray,x,y,mark);
       showDesk(someArray);
   }
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `std::vector` or a struct containing the array so that you can correctly track the dimensions more easily?

Comment: @james-mcnellis It's just learning c++ arrays ;)

Comment: Ok; I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`==` is comparison, `=` is assignment.

Your line:

```
someArray [x][y] == mark;
```

Does nothing.  It should be:

```
someArray [x][y] = mark;
```

Comment: Ohh... I have to sleep for a while :) Thanks.

Comment: @Ockonal: This is a very common source of bugs in C++ before you get 100% used to it, and even then it will sometimes happen.  Just another hairy point in the language.

Answer (score 0):

`someArray [x][y] == mark` tests the array to see if its equal to mark, but never actually sets it to anything...